# How long before I can retrieve signed document?

Tags: docusignapi

I understand how to send a request for a document to be signed in my app. It works perfectly.  I also understand that I can either poll the Docusign platform or be pushed notifications using DocuSign Connect (aka webhooks).

I'm kind of seeing a 2-phased implementation.  *Signing* being the first phase, and *Retrieval* being the second.   But I'm hoping this can be implemented in one synchronous process.

These are my two questions:

1. Can I immediately download/retrieve the signed document **as part of** the initial signing process somehow?  Or, is the only way to retrieve the signed document via an asynchronous poll/push?
2. After the signer completes the signing process, can I **immediately** retrieve the signed document?  If not, how long after the signer completes the signing process could it take before I can download/retrieve the signed document? I'm hoping this is a split-second thing, and that I don't have to wait a minute to retrieve the signed document.

I understand HOW to do this stuff. My questions revolve around - how QUICKLY can a signed document be ready for retrieval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Via the API you can download the PDF from the DocuSign envelope at ANY time. However, if you download it prior to all signers completing it, you will see the 'in process' watermark, and basically have an incomplete document. So you will want to download it after all signers have completed - from my experience the signing experience will not re-direct the user (final signer) away from the signing experience UI until DocuSign has internally marked the PDF as completed. There is no 'minute' wait time required, so once the final signer sees the 'signing complete', feel free to download the PDF.

Comment: "There is no 'minute' wait time required, so once the final signer sees the 'signing complete', feel free to download the PDF." Seems to be the answer I was looking for.  Thank you.